# iPhone : Primitives getters and setters

Tags: iphone, types, primitive

I feel a bit miffed at the moment, I done a few iPhone projects that use floats and ints etc and all is fine.

I now using OpenGL and GLFloat[] C arrays etc and it seems unless I make methods to set / get them it crashes on the device (not the simulator).  Now as these are not setup as properties (I don't think c arrays can) it kind of makes sense.  However the project has been working for months without them.  It seems something in the code is wiping out anything float / ints to the point that the debugger can see an assigned value but accessing it crashes the phone.

As soon as I think I know something for this platform, something changes my mind lol.

The question is.

How do you properly declare and use float arrays (float[3]) and  ints (I usually do these as properties) so that you can set and get them.
Should you need to make your own methods to get and set them?

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but what's your question exactly?

Comment: If it worked before, maybe it is a small bug. What did you change? It is unlikely that it just stops working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties work the same way with primatives as Objects, except they get `assign`ed instead of `retain`ed:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int someInt;
```

Sorry, got a little hasty there.  C arrays are *not* supported with properties.  You will have to roll your own getter/setter for C arrays.  If you still want to have a property, you can use an NSArray of `GLfloat` primatives.

Comment: That did not work for arrays
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLfloat[3] center;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLfloat[] center;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLfloat center[3];

Comment: Yeah I started building my own getters and setters and seems to work but how on earth i got as far as I did without it crashing is beyond me.  I have a working old copy with no getters or setters and it works fine